# Catalog price rules are not working if I had the dates in the rules.

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, discount, catalog-price-rules

I am building an e-commerce website named [bookslab.in](http://bookslab.in). I had added the catalog price rule of 10% OFF, but it is not getting visible on frontend. I had tried a lot, change dates, tried different types of conditions but still it is not visible.  I had used Simple product as Attribute Set for all products on my website. I had added the condition on all my books.  I had cleared the cache & done re-index as well. I had kept the priority "0". Any help will be appreciated. I had click on Apply rules as well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please provide you catalog Rule

Comment: Okzz i will provide  screenshot

Comment: I had provided the screenshot

Comment: Do you try clear cache or re-index?

Comment: I had tried but not working

Comment: @SalmanDalal Is that another rule create in website? If yes then set the priority of the rule.

Comment: But i had kept the priority to 0 but still it is not visible

Comment: Did you click the the "Apply Rules" button, so that all rules are actually applied?

Comment: I had done all this @arjen

Comment: @SalmanDalal is any other `catalog price rules` working ? what about `cron jobs` in site is working ?

Comment: Yeap cron job is working customers are getting emails

Comment: Only this catalog rule is active now

Comment: @SalmanDalal okay, if possible create one dummy `catalog price rule` and apply for that and check ,  if you want keep only 1 dummy product in that rule, also try by keeping  `from and to date` as blank and remove `0` from `priority` and check.....

Comment: Okzz i check & update u

Comment: done the same but not working.

Comment: have you click save & apply button? If not then click save & apply and check again front

Comment: Now i had saved by applying the rule, its working fine for all products, but whenever i add dates the rule does not work